# Name of the application to make bootable USBs from the contextual menu

Tags: usb, kubuntu, live-usb

What's the name of the application to make bootable USBs from contextual menu?

I want to see if I can install it on Kubuntu.

Comment: I found no evidence there ever was a right click context boot disk creator. The reason this is not viable is you would still have to configure all the variable (usb drive, format, persistence). The best you will get is setting default app for .iso files to the disk creator and then you can click them to start disk creator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Gnome/Unity you have `usb-creator-gtk`. For KDE, the alternative is `usb-creator-kde`

Comment: Thank you, now I can install a simple tool I really need for my production on any Ubuntu system at least.